# Is Cthulhu on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen a lot of Cthulhu questions on the Sci Fi stack exchange, would he be considered on topic here?

He would be considered a mythological creature wouldn't he, the same as The Minotaur or Medusa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are fictional mythologies on topic?](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/140/are-fictional-mythologies-on-topic)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cthulhu would come under the category of fictional mythologies.  It is the work of H.P.Lovecraft.

Therefore, as suggested in other posts, it is off-topic.

Comment: So The Minotaur is factual? Can you explain the difference?

Comment: The Minotaur is mythological, in that the story dates from time immemorial.  Cthulhu is the work of a modern author and questions can be addressed by the corpus of written work.

Comment: @Daft, I'm sure that the Science Fiction and Fantasy SE would more than welcome any questions about the Cthulhu mythos. Probably people there are better prepared than users here to answer questions about Lovecraft's work. I'm not saying that both interest are incompatible, but why trying to "force" this fictional mythos here when they already belong and fit well there and will get better answers?

Comment: Relax @Deion I didn't try to force anything. I was just curious, hence I asked on the meta.

Comment: @Daft, sorry, I should have chosen another word. Didn't pretend to say that   *you* specifically were trying to push these mythos into the site like in a "round hole square peg" situation. I understand that your *meta* question is asking for consensus. I was just pointing that it already seems to have a good place where it works well. I just wanted to point that even if **we** tried to find a reason to include them here as "on topic" we would be lowering the quality of answers received, since all the content would be "decentralized" in two different Stacks.

Comment: I believe the criteria currently is that there needed to be a significant number of "believers/followers" of the mythology rather than a time constraint.  Cthulhu is not really any sort of religion or belief and that is what makes it off topic.

Comment: @Chad so by your logic, questions about Scientology are on-topic?

Comment: @Daft - Those are not my standards they are the ones set out in this meta question: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/140/are-fictional-mythologies-on-topic?rq=1 and I would avocate that yes Scientology mythology would be on topic. Questions about the practice of Scientology would be off topic

Answer (score -1):

I have to disagree here.  All mythologies are fictional.  What makes Lovecraft distinct among modern mythologies is the degree to which his ideas have been consistently adopted by modern artists.  I see references ranging from horror classics like the Evil Dead, to children's films like Pacific Rim.

But this is just my humble opinion.